# Confusion With ExceptionLogger and ExceptionHandler - ASP.NET WebApi 2

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api2

My requirement is to handle exceptions globally. I throw business validation exceptions throughout my Business Logic layer and I need to handle these exceptions gracefully and return proper error messages to the caller.

I was following this article https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-asp-net-web-api-exception-handling-pipeline-a-guided-tour/

I'm very much confused as the above article says, ExceptionHandlers are only called if ExceptionFilters and ExceptionLoggers have not handled the exception.

I have default Application Insights Exception Filter which I thinks reports the exception to AI.

This article points out that I can have as many Exception Loggers but only one Exception Handler which is fine.

So...

1. Do I need to add AiHandleErrorAttribute on top of all the controllers? Or it'd work globally without adding on top of the controller? The below code is already there.

   ```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
   {
       filters.Add(new ErrorHandler.AiHandleErrorAttribute());
   }
   ```
2. If I add another Exception Logger to log the exception in Azure Storage it would work (along with the above AI Logger) right?
3. If I add an ExceptionHandler after all these, would it ever be called? As the above loggers would be called for logging the exception?

Comment: Hey! I'm asking myself the very same questions. Do you have anymore explanations now??